# Bind Window Icon to Image Control

Tags: c#, wpf

currently i have some problems with bindings in WPF.
My project is divided into 2 projects:
1. Library
2. Demo Project including the library.

My demo project has a main window with an icon.
Now in ViewModel of this window i open another window which is located in the Library. Then i set the icon of the window in the library to the icon of the main window from demo project.

The window of the library has an Image Control and i bound it to the icon of the window:

```
<Image Width="32" Height="32" Source="{Binding ElementName=windowPackageInformation, Path=Icon}" />
```

Window's icon is defined as follows:

```
Name="windowPackageInformation" Icon="/YPUS_LIB;component/icon_32x32.ico"
```

In the designer view the image is successfully showing up but when starting the application it fails with an exception saying that the icon is unable to locate.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: I don't think your Window in lib can access MainWindow via Element name as two have different VisualTree

Comment: Nah, that´s not the problem, the two definitions i gave are both in the same window. Icon assigning is just what happens before all of this. That´s not the problem.

Comment: not the definition.. you said that you are launching window from other project from you main window VM... the two windows have visualtrees of there own hence binding is not working

Comment: Forget about the main window. Its not even working when setting the icon in the library window manually.

Comment: where is your icon located? in library project or main project?

Comment: library project for now. Just for testing purposes but that´s not the problem. Icon is now located in library project where also is the window.

Comment: is the build action set to resource for icon?

Comment: Uhm, i want the icon to be compiled into the assembly later. For now it´s set to Content

Comment: it should be Resource if you want to access via package and try accessing like pack://application:,,,/YourReferencedAssembly;component/YourPossibleSubFolder/YourResourceFile.ico

Comment: Thank you, i changed it to "Resource" and it's working now.

Comment: great.. let me add it as an answer too.. for others to take benefit of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your icon (.ico) file should be added to the project you are planning to use it. `Build action` should be set to **Resource**.

Try accessing like `pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/PossibleSubFolder/Yo‌​urResourceFile.ico`

Comment: Thanks, this answer was a nice addition to my previous success.